# Adding jQuery TouchSwipe to prettyPhoto

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, swipe, prettyphoto

I am using [prettyPhoto](http://www.no-margin-for-errors.com/projects/prettyphoto-jquery-lightbox-clone/) for displaying images I get from Flickr. It is working great on the Desktop and on the iPad.
For the iPad I wanted to add swiping gestures for switching images. So I was trying to add [TouchSwipe](http://labs.skinkers.com/touchSwipe/).

Here is how I setup my prettyPhoto. Notice the callback.

```
function setupBox() {
    $("a[rel^='prettyPhoto[gallery1]']").prettyPhoto({
        slideshow: 5000,
        social_tools: '',
        animation_speed:'normal',
        theme:'facebook',
        changepicturecallback: function() {
            setupSwipe();
        }
    });
}
```

Here is the callback function. '#fullResImg' is the selector for the Image.

```
function setupSwipe() {
    $('#fullResImg').swipe({
        swipe:function(event, direction, distance, duration, fingerCount) {
            if( direction == 'left' ) {
                $.prettyPhoto.changePage('next');
            }else if ( direction == 'right' ) {
                $.prettyPhoto.changePage('previous');
            }
        },
        allowPageScroll: "none",
    });
}
```

All the functions are called correctly, but the swipe is not detected.
If I change the selector to '.pp_content' I can swipe in the bottom of the Box, but also not on the image itself.

I suspect, that it has something to do with the stacking of the box, but I stried several other selectors, which didn't work on the actual Image.

I'll include the markup of the pP Box here:

```
<div class="pp_pic_holder facebook" style="top: 90.5px; left: 80px; display: block; width: 816px;">
   <div class="ppt" style="opacity: 1; display: block; width: 776px;">LN-RKI</div>
   <div class="pp_top">
    <div class="pp_left"></div>
    <div class="pp_middle"></div>
    <div class="pp_right"></div>
   </div>
   <div class="pp_content_container">
    <div class="pp_left">
    <div class="pp_right">
     <div class="pp_content" style="height: 552px; width: 776px;">
      <div class="pp_loaderIcon" style="display: none;"></div>
      <div class="pp_fade" style="display: block;">
       <a href="#" class="pp_expand" title="Expand the image" style="display: inline;">Expand</a>
       <div class="pp_hoverContainer" style="height: 516px; width: 776px;">
        <a class="pp_next" href="#">next</a>
        <a class="pp_previous" href="#">previous</a>
       </div>
       <div id="pp_full_res"><img id="fullResImage" src="http://farm9.static.flickr.com/8489/8265747809_d0fca2a7c9_b.jpg" style="height: 516px; width: 776px;"></div>
       <div class="pp_details" style="width: 776px;">
        <div class="pp_nav" style=""><a href="#" class="pp_play">Play</a>
         <a href="#" class="pp_arrow_previous">Previous</a>
         <p class="currentTextHolder">1/50</p>
         <a href="#" class="pp_arrow_next">Next</a>
        </div>
        <p class="pp_description" style="display: none;"></p>
        <div class="pp_social"></div>
        <a class="pp_close" href="#">Close</a>
       </div>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="pp_bottom">
    <div class="pp_left"></div>
    <div class="pp_middle"></div>
    <div class="pp_right"></div>
   </div>
  </div>
 <div class="pp_overlay" style="opacity: 0.8; height: 954px; width: 959px; display: block;"></div>
```

So, has anyone here a clue on how to use TouchSwipe for swiping through images on prettyPhoto?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used the answer above to implement the same feature but with [TouchWipe](http://www.netcu.de/jquery-touchwipe-iphone-ipad-library) and found that instead of removing '.pp_hoverContainer' you can just add the swipe action to that element like so:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
        function setupBox() {
           $("a[rel^='prettyPhoto']").prettyPhoto({
                social_tools: false,
                theme:'dark_rounded',
                changepicturecallback: function() {
                    setupSwipe();
                }
           });
        }
        function setupSwipe() {
           $(".pp_hoverContainer").touchwipe({
            wipeLeft: function() { 
                $.prettyPhoto.changePage('next');
            },  
            wipeRight: function() { 
               $.prettyPhoto.changePage('previous');
        },
           min_move_x: 20,
           min_move_y: 20,
           preventDefaultEvents: true
       });
   }
   setupBox();
   });
```

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I found a workaround. Not very clean imho, but it is sufficent for this site.

I added the following code to the changepicturecallback:

```
if( document.width <= 1024 )
{
    $('.pp_hoverContainer').remove();
}
```

This completey removes the navigation overlay when the document width is <= 1024. This works on Android Chrome, iOS Chrome, iOS Safari.

I need to add, that I setup swipe on '#pp_full_res'. Not like in my question.

So yes, it was a stacking problem. Just to note, triggering the swipe on .pp_hoverContainer also did not work. Nice side effect: No navigation arrows in swipe mode :)

Answer (score 0):

I used of your code and only changed "#fullResImg" selector to ".pp_hoverContainer" then swipe worked for me.